# LINQ query from SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, api, entity-framework, linq

I'm developing an ASP .NET WEB API using entity framework. I have an SQL code which I have to rewrite in LINQ I tried different approaches but none did work. The code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    Debit, Credit, 
    (SELECT SUM(q.debit - q.Credit) 
     FROM Qry013 q 
     WHERE q.AccountGuide = 'D23265D8-E39A-4AF0-B652-0608FA61A866' 
       AND q.EntryNumber <= qry013.EntryNumber 
       AND q.ID <= qry013.ID) AS balance, 
    ISNULL(Entryname, InvoiceName) AS source,  
    ISNULL(EntryNumber, BillNumber) ASTransactionNumber,
    TBL001.CurrencyShortcut AS CurrencyName,
    Qry013.Rate, CostCenterName, BranchName, 
    EntryNote 
FROM
    Qry013 
INNER JOIN 
    TBL001 ON TBL001.CardGuide = Qry013.CurrencyGuide 
WHERE
    AccountGuide = 'D23265D8-E39A-4AF0-B652-0608FA61A866' 
    AND Posted = 1
```

Everything might seem easy but that part where there is a nested SELECT with a SUM operation. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Thank you @mark_s, I'm still new to stackoverflow

Comment: You don't need to convert everything to Linq. In EF, you can also execute raw sql select at entity and database level. Check  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: @CetinBasoz I tried something like that but I got the following error('The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'XtrDBModel.Qry013'. A member of the type, 'ID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.')

Comment: @CetinBasoz here is my code that I have tried: (var result = DBContext.Qry013.SqlQuery(@"my query went here").ToList();)

Comment: try creating a DTO entity class and map the query output to that. Ex: `(var result = DBContext.Qry013.SqlQuery<TEntityDTO>(@"my query went here").ToList();)`

Comment: @MuhammadRadwan, add your type. It is a good idea to add your models and sample data so you could get better answers which likely contain code. Without any effort from the question owner, chances of getting a good reply is low.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Yep it finally worked, I added a custom model from my sql quey and it worked like a charm, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a model class in which I defined the properties of the specific columns in the sql query and I used it as an object to populate the data in.